# FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory ERROR

Tags: python

```
football_players = []

while True:
    print("""
    *******************
    CHOOSE OPERATION:

    1. ADD FOOTBALLER (NAME SURNAME, FOOTBALL TEAM)
    2. SHOW ME PLAYERS OF FENERBAHÇE TEAM
    3. SHOW ME PLAYERS OF GALATASARAY TEAM

    ENTER 'q' to quit... 
    *******************    
    """)

    operation = input("Operation:")

    if (operation == "q"):
        break

    elif (operation == "1"):
        player = list()
        players_numbers = int(input("Kaç adet futbolcu ekleyeceksiniz?"))
        for i in range(players_numbers):
            player.append(input("Name Surname, Team:").split(","))

        with open("players.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
            for i in player:
                file.write("Name Surname:{} Team:{}\n".format(i[0], i[1]))

                if (i[1] == "Fenerbahçe"):
                    with open("fenerbahçe_players.txt", "a", encoding = "utf-8") as file2:
                        file2.write("Name Surname:{} Team:{}\n".format(i[0], i[1]))

                elif (i[1] == "Galatasaray"):
                    with open("galatasaray_players.txt", "a", encoding = "utf-8") as file3:
                        file3.write("Name Surname:{} Team:{}\n".format(i[0], i[1]))

    elif (operation == "2"):
        with open("fenerbahçe_players.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file2:      
            file2.readlines()

    elif (operation == "3"):
        with open("galatasaray_players.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file3:      
            file3.readlines()
```

I get this below error. And, i cant find the solution. I need to take player names from user and write these into `players.txt`. After that, I need to write 2 `.txt` file for their team. Can you help me, please?

```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'fenerbahçe_players.txt'
```

Comment: Place the full path or use os.getcwd()

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a file

````
with open("fenerbahçe_players.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file2:```
````

But that file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

First point: relative path are resolved against the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), not against the directory where your script or module is installed. The only safe solution is to use an absolute path - which can be constructed dynamically, using either the script or module path, some known system-specific location (ie `/home/<username>`on unices etc), or a user setting (using environment variable, a config file or whatever).

Second point: in all cases, if your user selects options 2 or 3 before he ever added any player (option 1), the team files have not been created yet, so of course they might not exist yet.